# Unicode: What Small Form Variants are used for?

Tags: unicode, cjk

There is an entire block in the Unicode containing punctuation symbols: [Small Form Variants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_Form_Variants). Wikipedia says it was added “for compatibility with the Chinese National Standard [CNS 11643](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNS_11643).” CNS 11643 article doesn't mention Small Form Variants. What are they actually used for?

Comment: I'd guess that *Small Form Variants* are used in Chinese texts instead of _common_ punctuation for some *visual* or *aesthetic* reason,  see [UAX #11: East Asian Width](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr11/) and [EastAsianWidth.txt](https://unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/EastAsianWidth.txt).

Comment: These links are about [Halfwidth and fullwidth forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halfwidth_and_fullwidth_forms), not about Small Form Variants.

Comment: But **all** characters from *Small Form Variants* Unicode block are classified as Wide (have set *East_Asian_Width* property as `W`). Fyi, here's meaning of abbreviations: `F` (Fullwidth), 
`H` (Halfwidth),
`W` (Wide), 
`Na`(Narrow),
`A` (Ambiguous),
`N` (Natural)/(Neutral)=(Not East Asian).

Comment: If Small Form Variants are wide it means that “… they tend to allow line breaks after each character and remain upright in vertical text layout.” It doesn't answer the question of how they are actually used: when a small form is used instead of a fullwidth for example.

Comment: Your question is interesting, but arguably off topic for SO. Perhaps consider asking instead [on superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/unicode) or [r/unicode on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Unicode/)?